# EXC_BAD_ACCESS, GCDAsyncUDPSocket

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access

I perform a very high throughput upload continuously and at some point in time i get this exception

[GCDAsyncUDPSocket.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R2Kq.png)

As i have enabled zombies i could po in the console with the zombie address and it returns number value and every time the exception occurs the zombie address is the same

[Zombie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAFWJ.png)

Any clues of how to debug this issue?

Comment: I tried using Instruments but this does not help because while using instruments the expected high throughput is not achieved and thus the exception never occurs. And on simulator too the exception never occurs.

Comment: I suggest trying out Xcode's "Address Sanitizer".  The thing being reported as an address may not be, especially if it repeats between runs.

Comment: Hello Philip, thanks for the tip, now the address is different. But still unable to print the class of the address in lldb.

Comment: I have also posted in the GitHub repo of CocoaAsyncSocket about the issue for more detailed description of the issue and its progress https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/issues/546

Comment: I think you've found a design flaw in GCDAsyncUDPSocket.  Whenever it completes a "send" operation, it looks in its queue to see if there's any work waiting to be done.  With enough queued packets, this creates what is effectively an infinite loop (see the three methods called repeatedly in your stack trace).  With too many of these calls you exhaust stack space and crash.

Comment: Ya I too thought so, but the unit test i created does not suffer the same infinite loop issue. I have uploaded the unit test code at GitHub link.